# how docker works if the OS environment changes?

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, devops

I am very new to docker. I have some very basic doubts on docker. suppose I am cloning a simple project from github. I want to create a docker image of that application. according to my OS(currently I am using linux), I am writing a docker file and building one image of that application, and from docker image I am creating a docker container. now my container is created. Now suppose my another team mate wants to deploy that docker image to other system of Windows/mac OS. now what are the procedures? means do I need to write the docker file again? or I need to pull the app from github again and following the same steps that I mentioned above? because in my dockerfile I have given commands according to my OS, but somebody wants to deploy the docker image in windows/mac.

And secondly, where is the image file located? in my local system it will not be there I know. how can I see the files/folders of the docker image?

I know this is very simple question to ask, still any help is highly appreciable.Thanks.

Comment: `where is the image file located?` Usually somewhere in `/var/lib/docker/`. Multiple overlayfs are stacked onto each other. `how can I see the files/folders of the docker image?` you can use `docker export` and save the container/image to a file and then unpack with tar. Or navigate `/var/lib/docker`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> suppose I am cloning a simple project from github. I want to create a docker image of that application. according to my OS(currently I am using linux), I am writing a docker file and building one image of that application, and from docker image I am creating a docker container. now my container is created.

Just to be sure that this is clear. You have to consider the "Docker Image" as "a recipe" and a "Docker Container" as "a cake". You can make as many cakes as you like with a given recipe. The recipe is what you share if you want to be able to re-bake cakes.

> Now suppose my another team mate wants to deploy that docker image to other system of Windows/mac OS. now what are the procedures? means do I need to write the docker file again? or I need to pull the app from github again and following the same steps that I mentioned above?

And thus it's the "image" that you will "share" with other developers and not the container. This can be done either by "pushing" the image to an online repository (e.g. https://hub.docker.com/) or by recreating the image every time from a Dockerfile.

> because in my dockerfile I have given commands according to my OS, but somebody wants to deploy the docker image in windows/mac.

I would have to see what exactly you are doing, but it's good practice to make docker images independent from the host. Or at least make it configurable during the first creation of the image or execution of the container.

To give a concrete example, in our company we have a private rest api written in PHP. Everything runs on docker, whether it is on development or on production. Our production images can be run on any OS, however our dev image will be built slightly differently depending on the OS. Why? Because we need to configure the debugger.

If the image is built on Linux, the php setting `xdebug.remote_host` needs to point to `localhost`, however when using `Docker For Mac`, then the php setting needs to be `docker.for.mac.localhost` .

The Dockerfile looks partially like this:

```
FROM adsdaq/print-engine-fpm:7.3

ARG DOCKER_HOST_ADDR

ENV PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST ${DOCKER_HOST_ADDR:-localhost}

COPY etc/dev/php/adsdaq.ini $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d/
```

And in the adsdaq.ini we have

```
xdebug.remote_host = ${PHP_XDEBUG_REMOTE_HOST}
```

And to simplify the life of our devs, we have a Makefile which handles OS detection:

```
DOCKER_HOST         ?= localhost
OPEN_BROWSER        ?= open
UNAME_S             := $(shell uname -s)

USERID=$(shell id -u)
GROUPID=$(shell id -g)

## Define variable depending on OS used, use xdg-open command
ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Linux)
    OPEN_BROWSER = xdg-open
else ifeq ($(UNAME_S),Darwin)
    ifneq (,$(wildcard /var/run/docker.sock))
      DOCKER_HOST = docker.for.mac.localhost
    endif
else
    $(warning Your OS "$(UNAME_S)" is not supported and could not work as expected!)
endif
```

As showed here, the image will be built differently on Linux than on Mac OS for dev purposes, and that is fine as we don't need to push those images on any repo manager.

If you need to share the image on a repo, then I would make sure that the configuration can be changed dynamically through parameters and/or eventually the usage of an [entrypoint script](https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data).

> And secondly, where is the image file located? in my local system it will not be there I know. how can I see the files/folders of the docker image?

You cannot see the files/folders of the docker image. To see what's in the image you need to run a container as it will give you an instance of it! Remember the cake/recipe analogy .. you cannot see the content of the cake until you baked it using the recipe.

You can however see all images "stored" on your machine by doing `docker images` .

Hope this helps figuring things out. Don't hesitate to share your Dockerfile if you need more assistance.

Comment: FROM node:6.11.5    
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install    
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]                                                                                                     and this is the sample application I want to dockerize.I'm building this image on ubuntu. so running the "docker run", container will be generated. I need to share the docker image with others. but I have built the image on ubuntu. how is it portable? And how will I share the image? will there be any physical file generated?

Comment: @MXDel Your sample hasn't anything OS specific. So whether this Dockerfile will be built on linux, windows or mac os the result will be the same. And so you can either let everyone built the dockerfile as explained above, or "push" it to a docker repository.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to change anything. Lets say your current host is Linux on which you are running docker and you made a dockerfile. Now lets say you went to another PC which is running on windows. If docker is running on this windows and you want to build/run or whatever using your image file then you can do that without changing anything.

For more detailed/specific answer you will have to post the dockerfile